# Using Azure B2C with PowerBI Embedded

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-ad-b2c, powerbi-embedded

Kick tires around. We want use Azure B2C for identity management for our web application that embeds PowerBI. PowerBi Embedded and the application are on a separate tenant that is used for our organization. Can this still be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Embed content for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers), also known as App owns Data.

1. User logs in using Azure B2C
2. Application back-end will verify user log-in and receive user details
3. Application back-end should [generate embed token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/generatetoken). This means that you need to understand how to link a B2C user to a report id / role etc. You can do this in your back-end based on metadata or a table lookup.

You can also include the username and roles if you would like to use Row Level Security (RLS).